# Resume event and click on notification causes duplication

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova, apple-push-notifications

Basically, I have an Angular app using Ionic Framework (based on Cordova so), that I run on iOS device.

In the main (parent) controller, I have this code:

```
    window.onNotificationAPN = function (event) {
        if (event.alert) {
            PushedNotificationPublisher.publish(angular.fromJson(event.data)); //custom publisher
    };

    document.addEventListener("resume", resume, false);
    function resume() {
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('onResumeApp');
        });
    }
```

Basically, it defines a `resume` function, (triggered when typing on the icon app from background), and a callback when a fresh notification is clicked in the banner.

On some controller, I listen to the pushed notification AND to the `resumeApp` event function.
The `resumeApp` event is necessary to refresh some data when the user clicks on the icon rather than the notification.
And the pusher is needed when the user has the app already in foreground, so that he just treats the notification.

When the app is in background and the user clicked on the notification, **both paths are executed**: the pusher and the resumeApp leading potentially to some duplication of treated data.
Indeed, the `resumeApp` triggers a full database refresh, while the notification adds some data, contained of course by the database refresh.

Is there an efficient way to avoid to treat the resume event when the user clicks on a notification in the banner.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty easy, I've just found it:

```
    window.onNotificationAPN = function (event) {
        if (event.foreground == 1 && event.alert) {  //detect if the app was still on foreground
            PushedNotificationPublisher.publish(angular.fromJson(event.data)); //custom publisher
    };
```

Otherwise, if the app was in background, only the `resume` event does the trick.